# Send Darwinians through Teleporter

Tags: darwinia

I'm in the 2nd world and have taken over all the gates but I need to get 150 darwinians underneath the tree in the middle.

No matter what I try with setting the location of an officers orders I can't get the darwinans through the teleporter.

IS this even possible?

Comment: I don't recall getting stuck on here, but it's been years so I don't recall if there's a trick to it either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahhh I hadn't aligned the dishes from both sides so I was only able to travel in 1 direction. Silly me.